# Address of and dereference on a pointer

Tags: c++

I came across this function in 'The C++ programming language' book.

```
template<typename In, typename Out> 
Out uninitialized_move(In b, In e, Out oo) {  
    using T = Value_type<Out>; // assume suitably defined type function (§5.4.2.1, §28.2.4)  
    for (; b!=e; ++b,++oo) {  
        new(static_cast<void*>(&*oo)) T{move(*b)}; // move construct  
        b–>~T(); // destroy
    }  
    return oo; 
}
```

The placement new parameter is **&*oo**

Why does it need **&*** in that statement 
?
Why won't just passing 'oo' work?

Comment: What happens if `oo` is an iterator?

Comment: In C++, as opposed to C, operators `&*` do not necessarily "annihilate" each other, since they can be overloaded. Even this `&*` is not enought to guarantee that `&` produces a "real" pointer, since `&` can be overloaded to do something completely different. This is why we have `std::addressof` now.

Answer (score 3):

In case `oo` isn't a pointer and has no `operator T*()` overload, you can't pass it directly as a pointer.

Some class objects, particularly iterators (like `std::vector::iterator`), implements something like

```
SomeStuff& SomeClass::operator*(void);
```

so that they can be "dereferenced" *as if* they were pointers. This is called operator overloading.

If you want to pass it directly, you must ensure there's such a member function like

```
SomeClass::operator T*(void);
```

In this way such objects can be implicitly converted to the corresponding pointers by calling that function. Otherwise you have to "dereference" it and then take the address of the dereferenced object.

Comment: Note that this isn't technically valid according to the standard (you're dereferencing a pointer to uninitialized memory, OR you're failing to destruct what's already there), but it's generally accepted and there isn't yet an idiomatic way to do this (though there is a proposal for one).

Answer (score 1):

Although you are correct about `&` and `*` cancelling each other out for pointers, `uninitialized_move` is a template function, so `oo` could be of non-pointer type that has a custom dereference operator `*`, e.g. an iterator.

For types like that an explicit "round-trip" is required to ensure that `static_cast` is applied to a pointer.